# update the multiple partial view using Jquery , MVC and Json not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to update the multiple partial view using Jquery , MVC and Json . 
My partial views are not updating

Here is my code 
My View code is

```js
@model DropdownGrid.Models.MyMultipleUpdateViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function _Complete(data) {
        var JsonObj = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
        alert(JsonObj);
        alert(JsonObj.myTest1ViewModel.MyTestUpdate)
        alert(JsonObj.myTest2ViewModel.MyTestUpdate)
        $("#Div1").html(JsonObj);
        $("#Div2").html(JsonObj);
    }
</script>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<fieldset>
    <div id="Div1">
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("_MyTest1PartialView", Model); }
    </div>

    <div id="Div2">
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("_MyTest2PartialView", Model); }
    </div>
    
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateStudent", "GetStudents",
        new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post",  OnComplete = "_Complete" }))
    {

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    }
</fieldset>
```

My Controller code is

```
enter code here

    public class GetStudentsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MyMultipleUpdateViewModel obj = new MyMultipleUpdateViewModel();
        obj.myTest1ViewModel = new MyTest1ViewModel();
        obj.myTest1ViewModel.MyTestUpdate = "Test1";

        obj.myTest2ViewModel = new MyTest2ViewModel();
        obj.myTest2ViewModel.MyTestUpdate = "Test2";

        return View(obj);
    }



    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateStudent(MyMultipleUpdateViewModel objuserloginmodel)
    {
        MyMultipleUpdateViewModel obj = new MyMultipleUpdateViewModel();
        obj.myTest1ViewModel = new MyTest1ViewModel();
        obj.myTest1ViewModel.MyTestUpdate = "Test1"+DateTime.Now.ToString();

        obj.myTest2ViewModel = new MyTest2ViewModel();
        obj.myTest2ViewModel.MyTestUpdate = "Test2" + DateTime.Now.ToString();

        return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

And My View model is

```
public class MyTest1ViewModel
{
    public string MyTestUpdate;
}

public class MyTest2ViewModel
{
    public string MyTestUpdate;
}


public class MyMultipleUpdateViewModel
{
    public MyTest1ViewModel myTest1ViewModel;

    public MyTest2ViewModel myTest2ViewModel;
}
```

It is not working 
Could you please help me to resolve my issue.

Comment: There is so much wrong here its hard to know where to start. You need to remove the `MyMultipleUpdateViewModel objuserloginmodel` parameter from the `CreateStudent()` method. But your returning json, not a view so what are you expecting `$("#Div1").html(JsonObj);` to display? And why does your method have `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` when its a `[HttpPost]`. And why are you not just using the `UpdateTargetId` ajax option to update the element.

Comment: And since the object your returning does not have a property named `responseText`, then `var JsonObj = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);` wont do anything except throw an error

Comment: I done all the Suggested changes . Just tell me how can I update multiple partial views using update target id ?

Comment: Return a partial view comprising the 2 partial views and replace the fieldset. But its impossible to understand what your really trying to do with this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your Action method, you are returning a JSON structure like this

```
{
    "myTest1ViewModel": {
        "MyTestUpdate": "Test112/12/2015 5:04:57 PM"
    },
    "myTest2ViewModel": {
        "MyTestUpdate": "Test212/12/2015 5:04:57 PM"
    }
}
```

But in your code, you are trying to pass the json object to the `html` method. you are ideally supposed to pass some html markup to html method.
Since you are having a Json object, you should read the properties of the json object and explicitly set each and every element markup, provided your partial view has items with unique ids.

Assuming your partial view looks like this

```
@model MyMultipleUpdateViewModel
<div id="testUpdate">@Model.myTest1ViewModel.MyTestUpdate </div>
```

Inside your javascript method, you can set the markup on the div.

```
function _Complete(data) {
  var JsonObj = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);

  $("#testUpdate").html(JsonObj.myTest1ViewModel.MyTestUpdate);
  // You may set other properties as well.     

}
```